# Dash that brakes when used on the ground on my godot 4.2 3D project

Tags: 3d, godot, gdscript, godot4

I'm a new developer on godot and I added a dash to my game. It works perfectly EXCEPT that if I run without pressing any direction keys, on the ground, my dash will brake and I don't know why.

I tried to see what the problem was with several methods but only learned that the speed decreases quickly if I dash on the ground. In air, there is no problem, the dash work totally fine

Here is the code

```
if Input.is_action_just_pressed("dash") and can_dash:
        dashing = true
        can_dash = false
        dash_timer.start()
        dash_again_timer.start()
        # Dash sans mouvement du joueur
        if input_dir == Vector2.ZERO:
            direction = transform.basis * Vector3(0, 0, -1)
            
        # Dash avec mouvement du joueur
        else:
            direction = transform.basis * Vector3(input_dir.x, 0, input_dir.y)
```

```
    if dashing: 
        current_speed = DASH_SPEED
    else:
        current_speed = WALKING_SPEED
    direction = lerp(direction, (transform.basis * Vector3(input_dir.x, 0, input_dir.y)).normalized(), delta * current_lerp_speed)
    

    velocity.x = direction.x * current_speed
    velocity.z = direction.z * current_speed
```